# In what order webpack loaders specified in separate rules are applied?

Tags: webpack

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(jsx|es6)$/,
    loader: "A-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
    loader: "B-loader"
  }
]
```

Will it be bottom to top for .jsx files?

ps Yes, I know there are pre and post loaders, I just wonder :-)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234329/what-is-the-loader-order-for-webpack

Comment: This actually isn't a duplicate - there the tests are the same, so it's obvious you can combine the two rules. Here (and in my case), the tests are different, and it's not clear whether or not that affects things.