# Webpack async loader priority order

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-3, webpack-loader

I wanna replace some code from each typescrpit during webpack compilation.
Now I have got something like this:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                loader: [
                    {

                        "loader": "test-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: [
                    {
                        "loader": "@ngtools/webpack",
                        "options": {
                            "tsConfigPath": "tsconfig.json",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

And my **test-loader** looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (source, map) {
  var callback = this.async();

  source = myReplaceFunction(source)

  this.cacheable && this.cacheable();
  callback(null, source, map);
};
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234329/what-is-the-loader-order-for-webpack) my loader (*test-loader*) should be called for each typescript file (and it is). Next loader (*@ngtools/webpack*) should be operating on modified (by *test-loader*) typescript files, but isn't, **why is that** ?

My configuration:

- **webpack** v3.10.0
- **typescript** 2.6.2
- **node** v9.4.0
- **@ngtools/webpack** v1.10.0-beta.3 (same situation for 1.6.4)

Without `enforce: 'pre'` same effect.
I am trying to do something like [this](https://github.com/jamesandersen/string-replace-webpack-plugin), but simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the source for @ngtools/webpack (`node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js`), you will notice that the loader does *not* take any input from the previous loader. Instead it grabs the filename `const sourceFileName = this.resourcePath;` which is your source Typescript file and converts it to Javascript. Therefore Angular completely ignores any pre-loaders you inject and grabs directly from source.

Hope it helps